# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ionic2, lodash, angularfire2

i'm trying to loop through an array of user data using lodash and angularfire2 but i get ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined

typical push array
                [
                    0: user1,
                    1: user2,
                    2: user3,
                ]

```
            import { AngularFireDatabase} from 'angularfire2/database';
            import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
            import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';;
            import * as _ from 'lodash';

            constructor( 
                private db             : AngularFireDatabase, 
                private afAuth         : AngularFireAuth) {}




            addGroupChats(allGroupMember) {
            console.log("allGroupMember", allGroupMember);

              //this line work well without error
              console.log("value[0]", allGroupMember.users[0]);
              //let endpoint = this.db.object(`/users/${allGroupMember.users[0]}/groups/${allGroupMember.groupUid}`);
              //endpoint.set(true); 

                this line throws ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined
              _.forEach(allGroupMember.users, function(value) {
                  let endpoint = this.db.object(`/users/${value}/groups/${allGroupMember.groupUid}`);
                  endpoint.set(true);      
              });
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for callbacks.
The `this` refers to the function object rather than the class in your case.
here:

```
_.forEach(allGroupMember.users,(value) => {
                  let endpoint = this.db.object(`/users/${value}/groups/${allGroupMember.groupUid}`);
                  endpoint.set(true);      
              })
```

Comment: Also, the use of lodash for iteration is pointless when using Typescript/ES The original code could be written more concise just with akkGroupMember.users.forEach( user => ...)